# Parse JSON in nodejs request

Tags: json, node.js, parsing

I have a little probleme with my request in NodeJs I want to parse my JSON, but I want dispaly the ***msg.errors.email.message*** who containt the message erros about my valdiation.

***My errors :***

```
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'errors' of undefined
```

***Code nodejs :***

```
if (err) {
   return res.status(500).json({ msg: err.msg.errors.email.message });
}
```

**Retour json ***

```
{
"msg": {
    "errors": {
        "email": {
            "message": "Is not a valid e-mail.",
            "name": "ValidatorError",
            "properties": {
                "message": "Is not a valid e-mail.",
                "type": "user defined",
                "path": "email",
                "value": "f@f"
            },
            "kind": "user defined",
            "path": "email",
            "value": "f@f",
            "$isValidatorError": true
        },
        "password": {
            "message": "Password needs to have at least one lower case, one uppercase, one number, one special character, and must be at least 8 characters but no more than 35.",
            "name": "ValidatorError",
            "properties": {
                "message": "Password needs to have at least one lower case, one uppercase, one number, one special character, and must be at least 8 characters but no more than 35.",
                "type": "user defined",
                "path": "password",
                "value": "dede-DSQds"
            },
            "kind": "user defined",
            "path": "password",
            "value": "dede-DSQds",
            "$isValidatorError": true
        }
    },
    "_message": "users validation failed",
    "message": "users validation failed: email: Is not a valid e-mail., password: Password needs to have at least one lower case, one uppercase, one number, one special character, and must be at least 8 characters but no more than 35.",
    "name": "ValidationError"
}
```

}

***I want dispaly***

msg.errors.email.message

Comment: So, `return res.status(500).json({ msg: err.msg.errors.email.message });` ?

Comment: non its not return message

Comment: Can you show more of you function block?

Comment: return res.status(500).json({ msg: err.errors.email.message });                Correct answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just have to return that ?

```
if (err) {
   return res.status(500).json({ msg: err.msg.errors.email.message });
}
```

Hope it  helps.